# How to increase pandas explode function performance?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I have data as below in a dataframe

| FID | SID_START | SID_END |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 404915 | 1 | 3 |

and this should be expanded as below

| FID | SID |
| --- | --- |
| 404915 | 1 |
| 404915 | 2 |
| 404915 | 3 |

So I can group by SID to get the count

I have around  480 million rows and I am using explode function in pandas

```py
df['SID'] = [pd.Series(range(left,right+1)) for left, right in 
             zip(df['SID_START'],df['SID_END'])]


df= df.explode('SID').drop(['SID_START', 'SID_END'], axis=1)
```

and its taking around 10 minutes for 10 million records is there a fasetr way in python to handle this
?

Comment: Then how can I get the range of values between those column values ?

Comment: Sorry missed the explode part adeedd now

Answer (score 3):

Pandas is probably not a good choice for 480 millions records.. having said that here is one approach which utilizes the numpys repeat function to explode the dataframe in a efficient manner

```
# calculate diff between end and start
n = df['SID_END'] - df['SID_START'] + 1

# repeat the index n times
df1 = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(n))

# Use cumcount to create sequential counter per group
# then add this with SID_START to calculate the SID
df1['SID'] = df['SID_START'] + df1.groupby('FID').cumcount()
```

---

Input

```
      FID  SID_START  SID_END
0  404915          1        3
1  404916          5       10
```

Output

```
      FID  SID_START  SID_END  SID
0  404915          1        3    1
0  404915          1        3    2
0  404915          1        3    3
1  404916          5       10    5
1  404916          5       10    6
1  404916          5       10    7
1  404916          5       10    8
1  404916          5       10    9
1  404916          5       10   10
```

Comment: Sharama , Thank you , this worked very well and was able to process 10 million rows in 5 seconds :) but in my dat  FID is not unique and few rows can be like this        FID  SID_START  SID_END
404915          1        3            404915          7        10 , there rows are generating wrong ranges

Comment: Group by index would solve this problem   df1['SID'] = df['SID_START'] + df1.groupby(df1.index).cumcount()

Comment: @abcd_1234 Glad to help. yes, if FID is not unique then groupby index would be best.

Comment: df1['SID'] = df['SID_START'] + df1.groupby('FID').cumcount() this statement is taking lot of memory , even using the same column in LHS df1['SID_START'] = df['SID_START'] + df1.groupby('FID').cumcount() , is there a way to reduce the memory ? anything inplace to alter an existing column with new values ?